# Google redirect URI stopped working without HTTPS

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I have a non-production app in which the redirect URI is set as follows with **HTTP**

[image]

But when a user tries to authenticate the following comes up which has the URL with **HTTPS** instead of **HTTP**

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details comply with Google policies.
redirect_uri: https://localhost/index.php?entryPoint=GSuiteOauth2callback
```

[image]

### Question

Why is it looking for the HTTPS version when it's the HTTP version that's in the redirect URIs list?

If I set it as HTTPS in redirect URIs it will work, but when user authorizes it breaks. Can we not use **HTTP** version of the redirect URI in test apps which haven't been published yet?

Comment: Make sure you using the http:// scheme in the redirect_uri value that you pass to the Google OAuth endpoint (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_3). You get this error if that value passed doesnt match any of the "Authorized Redirect URIs:" set up in the console. The HTTP scheme must also match